# Make a PATCH or PUT request using $resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to create an update function in an angular controller:

```
$scope.update = function(product){
    product.$save();
    $scope.cancelEdit();
}
```

My backend has two routes for updating a resource:

```
PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)
PUT    /products/:id(.:format)
```

However, I can't access either of these using `$resource`! [According to the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), I can either use these functions to send requests with certain http verbs:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

So how am I meant to send a PATCH or PUT request?

**HOW SHOULD I CONFIGURE THIS IN MY APP CENTRALLY?**

Answer (score 2):

These are just the defaults, but [per the documentation for `$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage) you can define your own actions.

```
$resource(url, paramDefaults, {
   put: {method: 'PUT'},
   patch: {method: 'PATCH'},
});
```

Comment: Only started learning angular a few days ago... Where should you put this configuration to make a central change? Can I put in the `config` function? i.e. `angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']).config(function($resource{ ...`??